# Is it the right way to end request-response cycle in nodejs/express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware function `auth_deviceid` in my nodejs/express project to check the `device_id` submitted. The request-response cycle should be terminated if the device_id does not meet certain condition. I am wondering if my code is correct to end the request-response cycle. Here is the `auth_deviceid`:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const user_device_id = (req.query._device_id || req.body._device_id);
    if (!user_device_id || user_device_id.length < 10) return res.status(400).send('Missing device id!');

    next();
}
```

The above middleware function is called in route:

```
router.post('/verif', [auth_deviceid], async (req, res) => {....}
```

My question is that if the `user_device_id` is empty, will the router.post above be rejected (`auth_deviceid` return false)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, looks fine - if the condition is not met, you are returning via `res.send()` which calls `res.end()` internally.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of call `res.send` in a middleware, let's `next` with a error, then handle all of errors by only one error handler.

The middleware

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const user_device_id = (req.query._device_id || req.body._device_id);
    if (!user_device_id || user_device_id.length < 10) return next(new Error('MISSING_DEVICE_ID'));
    // I like a custom error like `new MissingDeviceError()`

    next();
}
```

Then, in your error handler of express app, just check type of error:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  if (err.message === 'MISSING_DEVICE_ID') {
    return res.status(400).send('Missing device id!');
  }
  // another error
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```